# Django | mysql | no such table: django_session

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, django-orm

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти мою ошибку)
Я перенёс свой Django-проект на mysql я сделал успешную миграцию: https://skr.sh/sFCNxTMyiuU, но получаю ошибку уже после старта.

> no such table: django_session:

https://skr.sh/sFCbdrBwloe
(Меня немного смущает, что ошибка от sqlite3/base.py

Вот так выглядят мои DATABASES: https://skr.sh/sFChwGsQmaH (User и Name - одно значение)
Я пытался вводить в name название Бд, но тогда получаю ошибку доступов

```
(1045, "Access denied for user '......'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

Также, у меня, помимо созданной успешно mysql, создалась пустая sqlite. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'users.apps.UsersConfig',
        'main.apps.MainConfig',
        'feedback.apps.FeedbackConfig',
        'billing.apps.BillingConfig',
    
        'rest_framework',
    
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

....Когда я делал свою первую миграцию - я получал No changes detected..Поэтому тогда я сделал migrate, а потом повторил makemigrations и migrate.
Django'вские тоже не подтягивались

Выглядит так, будто бы он таблицу ищет в той БД, которую сам же и создал дефолтно (которая пустая)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значит видимо где-то косяк в настройках, раз они по какой-то причине не считываются

Comment: Это мне было известно на момент написания поста)) Но куда посмотреть?